# How do I make uploaded content uploaded from many servers

Tags: file, distributed

I have this kind of problem. I have created a web application and I am going to run it on a dedicated server. Users will be able to upload photos and other kind of files. If the users increase I add another server. 
So they become two like in the picture below. Now since the files are being uploaded to my applications root folder, I think the new server won't be able to read those files. How can I accomplish to store files in a way that whatever server a user will be connecting to he will be able to retrieve the file. How are the cheaper computers (small ones in the ring) connected so that they store files like one big drive with one giant folder such that whenever I want to increase storage I just add another cheap computer to the ring. What do I need to search for in the web?

please pardon me for my poor English. I had asked a similar question before but nobody answered so I thought the photo might help. I am willing to learn anything new to solve this problem. [my other earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497560/how-to-store-limitless-number-of-files)
[image: description]

Comment: I think you'd get better answers if your question didn't pre-suppose that you wanted to leave images on a local hard drive -- because that's a horrible idea. If your question was: How do I make uploaded content accessible from many servers, then we could talk about uploading the content to Akamai, or storing it in a database, etc.

Comment: @user814064 thank your for your response, I have edited the question appropriately. I don't intend to store the files locally In my mind I had assumed that the ring is a network over the internet. I also don't think that the solution for storing the files in a database will work because the cassandra database im using is said not to do well with files. Is akamai the best solution that there is?

Comment: I'd upload the images to Akamai and just make the URL of the image available to each server. You can try searching for: cassandra as a "content delivery network" and see what you find.

Comment: I have checked Akamai out and unfortunately its too expensive for me. I will just stick to local storage and consider using CDNs when hit a performance bottle neck. more like cross that bridge when I get there.